# avoid overflow of inner div's if it exceeds the size of outer div and display them in next line

Tags: html, css

I don't know how to phrase my problem 
but here is my issue
i have a outer div of size 900px 
and inside that div i have 8 inner div each of size 250px 
so on each line i can have only 3 div and the rest of div has to come on next line but i am not getting how to do this. 
here is my code

```
 <div class="big">
                        <div class="wrapper">
                            <a href="#"><div></div></a>
                        </div>
                         ....some more div
                         ....
</div>
```

and here is my css code

```
 .big{
         display:-webkit-box;
         width:900px;
    }
.wrapper {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
    background-color:red;
    margin-right:2px;
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sabaShaikh/qtujvLkx/)

please help me with this

Answer (score 0):

Add `display: inline-block;` into style of `wrapper` class.